# jQCloud - how to clear it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script for showing a tag-cloud from [here](https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud).

```
var word_list = getTags();
$("#example").jQCloud(word_list); 


<div id='example'></div>
```

I'm loading the tags dynamically from different sources by clicking on a button. The first time it shows the the tags properly, but the next time it "adds them up" to the tags that are already there. I need to clear or refresh the tag-cloud somehow, I tried this:

```
$('#example').val('');
```

and there was no luck.

Is there a way to do it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using this:

```
$('#example').html("");
```

The .val method is primarily used to get or set the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. It won't set the value of the div as you are trying to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `empty()` to remove all child nodes from your div and then call `$("#example").jQCloud(word_list);` again so that you can fill it up with new ones

Try:

```
$('#example').empty();
```

Comment: I had to call `$('#example').empty()` followed by `$('#example').jQCloud('destroy');` so that I could regenerate the word cloud successfully.